# C++ program with pointer shows unusual behaviour

Tags: c++, c++17

So I'm writing a code to implement a data structure somewhat similar to a partial trie. Here's the code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include"utils.h"

using namespace std;

template<std::size_t N>
struct node_x_t {
    static_assert(N <= 256, "N must be <= 256");
    int num_elements;
    char chars[N];
    node_x_t<256>* children[N];
};

node_x_t<256>* root;

node_x_t<256>* createNode(char c){
    node_x_t<1>* temp = new node_x_t<1>;
    temp->num_elements = 1;
    temp->chars[0] = c;
    temp->children[0] = NULL;
    return (node_x_t<256>*)temp;
}

void add(string key){
    node_x_t<256>* nav = root;
    node_x_t<256>* prev = root;
    int prevIdx=0;
    int size = key.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int idx = -1;
        if(nav==NULL){
            nav = createNode(key[i]);
            if(i!=0){
                prev->children[prevIdx] = nav;
                prev = nav;
                prevIdx=0;
            }
            else{
                prev = nav;
                root = nav;
                prevIdx=0;
            }
            cout<<"NEW: "<<nav->chars[0]<<" ";
            nav = nav->children[0];
            continue;
        }

        int nodeSize = nav->num_elements;
        for(int j=0;j<nodeSize;j++){
            if(nav->chars[j] == key[i]){
                idx = j;
                break;
            }
        }

           
        if(idx!=-1){
            prev = nav;
            prevIdx = idx;
            nav = nav->children[idx];
            cout<<"HIT: "<<prev->chars[idx]<<" ";
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}


void test(){
    root=createNode('0');
    add("a");
    add("ab");
    add("abc");
    add("abcd");
    add("abcde");
    add("abcdef");
    add("abcdefg");
    add("abcdefgh");
    add("abcdefghi");
    add("abcdefghij");
    add("abcdefghijk");
}

int main(){
    test();
}
```

The `chars[]` array stores the character next to the current node and the `children[]` array has a pointer to the node containing the next character

I have added "NEW" and "HIT" statements to indicate whether the prefix of the current string to be added has already been added earlier(testing purposes).

Here's the output

```
NEW: a 
HIT: a NEW: b 
HIT: a HIT: b NEW: c 
HIT: a HIT: b HIT: c NEW: d 
HIT: a HIT: b HIT: c HIT: d NEW: e 
HIT: a HIT: b HIT: c HIT: d HIT: e NEW: f 
HIT: a HIT: b HIT: c HIT: d HIT: e HIT: f NEW: g 
HIT: a HIT: b HIT: c HIT: d HIT: e HIT: f HIT: g NEW: h 
HIT: a HIT: b HIT: c HIT: d HIT: e HIT: f HIT: g HIT: h NEW: i 
HIT: a HIT: b HIT: c HIT: d HIT: e HIT: f HIT: g HIT: h HIT: i NEW: j 
HIT: a HIT: b NEW: c NEW: d NEW: e NEW: f NEW: g NEW: h NEW: i NEW: j NEW: k
```

Basically after the 10th string is added, it seems like most of the nodes are deleted automatically and are created again. However, ideally the code must have given a `HIT` for the string "abcdefghijk" as well.Could you find the bug in the code?

Comment: why do you have so many casts? `(node_x_t<256>*)root` looks wrong.

Comment: There's no wrong in such casts right?

Comment: there is no correct in that cast. `root` points to a `node_x_t<1>` not to a `node_x_t<256>`

Comment: @ShivaGanesh C-style casts are almost always wrong. Mainly because they allow you to weird things unchecked. C++ `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` are much more expressive and allow the compiler to run more checks.

Comment: `return (node_t*)temp;` but `temp` is `node_x_t<1>*`.

Comment: @churill yeah `reinterpret_cast` is very expressive.

Comment: Maybe what you actually want is `return  &temp->base;`

Comment: I have updated the code. But it still doesn't gives me the expected output

Comment: `return (node_x_t<256>*)temp;` that is just invalid. `node_x_t<1>` is not `node_x_t<256>`.

Comment: See also [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102)

Comment: The use of templates in this endeavor makes no sense *at all*. And I suspect the difference between *compile-time* vs. *run-time* is blurred sufficiently for you to not see that.

Answer (score 2):

> Could you find the bug in the code?

The bug in your code is the assumption that template types can be cast to each other with modified template parameters. That assumption is just plainly wrong. `node_x_t<1>` is a **different** type then `node_x_t<256>` and accessing one object using a pointer to the other type is just as wrong as accessing a `double` via an `int` pointer. Overall, if you cast pointers or use `reinterpret_cast` it could be that you should rethink your approach.

In this case, `node_x_t` could dynamically allocate the number of elements it stores, if the intention is that the number of elements changes *on runtime*. For example, something along:

```
struct node_x_t {
    node_x_t(std::size_t N) : num_elements(N), chars(N), children(N)
    {
        assert(N <= 256); // TODO: throw exception
    }
    node_x_t() : node_x_t(0) {}
    node_x_t(char c) : node_x_t(1) {
         chars.at(0) = c;
    }
    int num_elements;
    // at least use std::array
    std::vector<char> chars;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node_x_t>> children;
};
```

Or you could stick with a constant *compile-time* limit to number of elements, then you need to use only that single one type. Then your functions should also always use that template type. Really, these functions look like should be member functions.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct node_x_t {
    static_assert(N <= 256, "N must be <= 256");
    int num_elements;
    std::array<char, N> chars;
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<node_x_t>, N> children;

    static std::shared_ptr<node_x_t<N>> createNode(char c);
    void add(std::string key) {
       // maybe shared_ptr is too much - no idea, I do not understand the algorithm
       node_x_t<N>* nav = *this;
       node_x_t<N>* nav = *this; // use N everywhere!
       // blabla
    }
};
```